# Hydroxyl radicals effects on human body from drinking KDF copper/zinc filtered water

Tags: water, water-filter-purifier

There are many water filters that use KDF in place of, or in conjunction with, granular activated carbon filters to produce drinking or shower water by removing heavy metals and chlorine from it. It is also [known](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Copper_zinc_water_filtration) that the copper/zinc water filtration generates hydroxyl radicals that form during the process. Hydroxyl radicals are being [described](http://www.eurohealth-spain.com/articulos/the_dangerous.pdf) as very harmful to a human body:

> The uncontrolled action of hydroxyl radicals the most damaging free
>   radical by far can have devastating effects within the body. ... It
>   reacts at diffusion rates with virtually any molecule found in its
>   path including macromolecules such as DNA, membrane lipids, proteins,
>   and carbohydrates.

So is there a significant harm of using that kind of water filters for every day water consumption?

Comment: If you read the first link you posted closely there are situations described in the article, that recommends against using this kind of filtration. So, at least one answer to your question is in there: It depends on the situation.